# Is there any way of converting OpenCV.Mat to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opencv, mat

I'm working on Mat in OpenCV. However, I need to manually calculate the Mat by myself. Is there is a way of accessing Mat likes 2D array?

```
const myMat = cv.matFromArray(cv, 3, 3, cv.CV_64F, [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9],
    ])
const newMat = someProcessThatReturnMat(myMat)

/* OpenCV in JS cannot access Mat like this */
const result = someProcess(newMat[1][2], newMat[2][0])
```

Thank you in advance

**Updated**: The problem is `cv.matFromArray` cannot convert 2D array to Mat. You have to use it as 1D array. That's why it never return the correct values. For example:

```
const myMat = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_64F, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

And then, you can access the value

```
const value = myMat.doubleAt(1, 2) // row 1, col 2
```

Comment: very good observation! indeed it expects flat arrays... I did not notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `doubleAt(y,x)` method.

It's *double* because the mat's content is `CV_64F`, not because you want doubles.

You can also use `.data64F` to access a flat `Float64Array` of the Mat's data.

OpenCV.js is... *rough*. It originated from someone's Google Summer of Code and hasn't received significant care since. Documentation amounts to some tutorials; API docs seem to be missing entirely. The "Mat" interface emulated the `at()` method from C++, badly, instead of looking at numpy (python) or making this access feel "native" to javascript. Overloading the `[]` operator *is* possible using a `Proxy` but that was not implemented.

Here's an example: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d06/tutorial_js_basic_ops.html

Feel free to browse [OpenCV's issues](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?q=label%3A%22category%3A+javascript+%28js%29%22) and maybe suggest some improvements.

Comment: It doesn't work in JS. I tried both `.data64F` and `doubleAt(y,x)`. It didn't return the correct value.

Comment: you figured the reason out already: matFromArray insists being given a flat array. it chokes on nested arrays.